# Conditions in Multuithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans-8

I have this piece of code which is controlling two threads.

```
synchronized public void run() {
  switch(ThreadChoice){
      case 1:
      dataBase();
      break;
      case 2:
      ViewTotal.choice=1;new ViewTotal().displayDatabase();
     break;
  }
}
```

When i use **SWITCH** statement, it works fine but if i use **if,if-else or if-else-if**, it doesn't work correctly.
Here is the code with **if** statement.

```
synchronized public void run() {

  if(ThreadChoice==1)dataBase();
  else if(ThreadChoice==2)ViewTotal.choice=1;new ViewTotal().displayDatabase();
}
```

while using the **if** case, it executes the code in both the conditions but while using the **switch**, it only executes the specified case. can anybody please elaborate this . i am much confused in it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
if(ThreadChoice==1)dataBase();
else if(ThreadChoice==2)ViewTotal.choice=1;new ViewTotal().displayDatabase();
```

is the same as:

```
if(ThreadChoice==1) {
  dataBase();
} else if(ThreadChoice==2) {
  ViewTotal.choice=1;
}
new ViewTotal().displayDatabase();
```

If you want the `new ViewTotal().displayDatabase();` only to execute for `ThreadChoice==2`, you need to use braces, and put it inside the appropriate brace:

```
if(ThreadChoice==1)dataBase();
else if(ThreadChoice==2) { ViewTotal.choice=1;new ViewTotal().displayDatabase(); }
```

But it's a reasonably good idea always to use braces, and to put one statement per line, so your intent is clear.

Comment: but in this case **new ViewTotal().displayDatabase();** shouldn't work properly as my setting work fine if and only if both the statements  ViewTotal.choice=1; and new ViewTotal().displayDatabase(); execute at the same time

Comment: @NancyFronze I don't really follow what you are saying. Are you saying that putting things on the same line like `ViewTotal.choice=1;new ViewTotal().displayDatabase();` means the two statements execute concurrently? If you are, that's simply wrong: putting them on the same line or on separate lines makes no semantic difference.